How can I get Google Assistant to stop asking me what app to use for a note?
I have a Pixel 7.
For months now I've been using Keep for notes I enter by voice through Google Assistant.  It now longer works correctly.
Please help.  Thanks in advance.
Here's what I used to do
Press the Assistant button, say "take a note"
Assistant says, "alright, what would you like it to say"
I say, "get a new phone" or whatever
Assistant says, "alright, I've saved your note".
And the note shows up in Keep, either through my phone or through the web.
Life was grand.
Here's what happens now
Press the Assistant button, say "take a note"
Assistant says, "alright, what would you like it to say" (or sometimes "What do you want it to say?")
I say, "get a new phone" or whatever
Assistant says "Alright, which app do you want to use?"
OMG
I have to say "Keep".
What I want it to do
NOT FREAKING ASK ME WHAT APP TO USE EVERY FREAKING TIME!
What I've done to try to fix it.

Reboot - didn't help

Open Assistant Settings, verify Google Keep is checked - yes Keep is selected.

Open Assistant Settings, disable notes and lists, reenable - didn't help

Open Assistant Settings, disable notes and lists, reboot, reenable - didn't help

Install some other Notes and Lists provider - tried to install another list app.  Didn't make a difference

Tried Gemini - OMG, near as I can tell, Gemini doesn't even know what a note is.  Switched back to Assistant.  Still didn't fix the issue.

Remove Keep, reinstall - same problem


Possibly related
Immediately prior to this behavior I installed an additional Gmail account in the Gmail app.  I had three accounts installed, taking a note by voice worked fine.  Installed a fourth account, and taking a voice by note started asking which app.  Correlation does not imply causality, so I don't know that this was the cause.  But for what it's worth, I uninstalled the fourth account, and it didn't fix the issue.
Addendum
It works correctly in the car, through Android Auto.

So, it seems like the Keep app is itself the problem.
If I simply remove Keep then taking a note by voice works correctly.  Assistant will show notes in Keep using a browser.
If I reinstall Keep the problem comes back.
This is a decent work-around, but does not actually fix the issue, since Keep can't be installed.  Without the app installed, there's no offline functionality.

A workaround is to say "Take a note with [app name]" directly. E.g. "Take a note with Keep."
Although a bit wordy, this way, Google Assistant will not ask for which note app.

+1.  I will try that, thanks.  The problem did not fix itself overnight, sadly.

This has been a decent workaround, although one use case for me is to take a note when on my bike, with the phone attached to the handlebars.  I guess because of wind the phone consistently hears "Keep" as "Keith", which of course it does not recognize as a notes app, and leaves the phone very confused and the note fails to get recorded.
